# combining distinct on projection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is there a query i can use on the following collection to get the result at the bottom?

Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObectId(xyz),
    "name" : "Carl",
    "something":"else"
},
{
    "_id" : ObectId(aaa),
    "name" : "Lenny",
    "something":"else"
},
{
    "_id" : ObectId(bbb),
    "name" : "Carl",
    "something":"other"
}
```

I need a query to get this result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObectId(xyz),
    "name" : "Carl"
},
{
    "_id" : ObectId(aaa),
    "name" : "Lenny"
},
```

A set of documents with no identical names. Its not important which _ids are kept.

Comment: The specific problem is that i've got a table with a column(A) containing multiple identical strings and a unique column(B). I would like to remove all duplicates from A and keep the associated values from B. Distinct keeps afaik only the column it was used on.

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain the full details of what you're looking for? And to avoid confusion, it's better to refer to collections and document properties rather than tables and columns.

Comment: If the document _id value is not important, then why not simply use [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)?

Comment: its value does not matter. but it is mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use aggregation framework to get this shape, the query could look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [     
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$name",
           id: { $first: "$_id" }
         }
     },
     {
      $project:{
          _id:"$id",
          name:"$_id"
          }
      }   
   ]
)
```

As long as you don't need other fields this will be sufficient.
If you need to add other fields - please update document structure and expected result.

as you don't care about ids it can be simplified

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "$name"}}])
```